is there a way to fix about blank
it works in onecompiler but when i put it in webstudio it says it has a html validation and it wont let me put it in without "automaticly fixing the code" so i allow it to auto fix and then the button dosnt work. also i am really wanting it to launch in fullscreen with no border. here is my code and thanks for any help
<html>
 
  <head>
  </head>
 
  <body>
    <button>Fullscreen</button>
    <script>
      var urlObj = new window.URL(window.location.href);
      var url = "https://example.com/";
      if (url) {
        var win;
 
        document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
          if (win) {
            win.focus();
          } else {
            win = window.open();
            win.document.body.style.margin = '0';
            win.document.body.style.height = '100vh';
            var iframe = win.document.createElement('iframe');
            iframe.style.border = 'none';
            iframe.style.width = '100%';
            iframe.style.height = '100%';
            iframe.style.margin = '0';
            iframe.src = url;
            win.document.body.appendChild(iframe);
          }
          document.querySelector('button').style.bacground = 'grey';
          document.querySelector('button').innerHTML = "Play Now";
        };
      }
 
    </script>
  </body>
 
</html>

i have tried multipule diffrent codes and they all either have a white border or do not work at all
this is a code that works but has a white border
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Open Game</title>
<style>
    /* CSS */
    .button-92 {
        --c: #fff; /* text color */
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #0000 33%, #fff5, #0000 67%) var(--_p,100%)/300% no-repeat,
            #004dff; /* background color */
        color: #0000;
        border: none;
        transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(calc(20deg*var(--_i,-1)));
        text-shadow: calc(var(--_i,-1)* 0.08em) -.01em 0   var(--c),
            calc(var(--_i,-1)*-0.08em)  .01em 2px #0004;
        outline-offset: .1em;
        transition: 0.3s;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 2rem;
        margin: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: .1em .3em;
    }

    .button-92:hover,
    .button-92:focus-visible {
        --_p: 0%;
        --_i: 1;
    }

    .button-92:active {
        text-shadow: none;
        color: var(--c);
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 9e9q #0005;
        transition: 0s;
    }
</style>


<!-- HTML -->
<button class="button-92" role="button" onclick="openGame()">Button 92</button>

<script>
    function openGame() {
        var win = window.open(); // Open a new window
        var url = "https://example.com"; // URL to load
        var iframe = win.document.createElement('iframe'); // Create an iframe
        iframe.style.width = "100%"; // Set iframe width
        iframe.style.height = "100%"; // Set iframe height
        iframe.style.border = "none"; // Remove border
        iframe.src = url; // Set iframe source to the URL
        win.document.body.appendChild(iframe); // Append iframe to the new window
    }
</script>

